# how to fix gateway timeout error in php?

Tags: php, timeout, sms, gateway

Iam having a php file that sends text messages on mobile to all the users that i have in my database's particular table.
Now the entries are like 2000 or so in number and this number will keep on increasing.
On my page there is a small form that selects a list of the users to whom message is to be sent from a drop down and then user writes the text to be sent in a textarea and then on clicking the submit button php script stars sending the messages to mobile numbers.

Now while trying to send messages my browser has shown gateway timeout error but the script kept on running and messages are sent to the mobiles but not once but 6 times.
I checked my script my query and all the code is correct.This all happened coz of that gateway timeout.

Now does this gateway timeout kepts the script running again and again till the browser is not closed?? is this was the reason that a single message was sent 6 times to mobile numbers??
I mean how can i escape my file from getting this gateway error so that one message is sent only one time to a number??

Comment: "Gateway error" is a server connection issue, not a script issue. How do you get the messages from your script to the mobile numbers, are you using some web-to-mobile service?

Answer (score 0):

> how to fix gateway timeout error in php???

You can't that error is being reported by something in between you and where the script is running.

You can work around the problem by running the PHP script independently of the browser request: Go have a google for long running PHP processes or read [this](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html)

C.